# External Cookie for External Login in ASP.NET OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

We have a legacy system which is built on ASP.NET Mvc 4, now we would like to support Signal Sign On via Azure Active Directory for current users as well as new users. Since we have managed our own authentication workflow, ASP.NET Identity definitely does not fit in our case.

I have managed to build a demo which is working on OWIN OpenIdConnect middleware passive mode without using ASP.NET Identity. The below code works correctly:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType("ExternalCookie");
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        ClientId = ClientId,
        Authority = Authority

        // More code
    });
```

And in `ExternalLoginCallback` action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var authManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

    var result = await authManager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
    authManager.SignOut("ExternalCookie");

    //More code to convert to local identity
}
```

This case is really common even using other providers like Google, Facebook or Twitter. One thing I have not much clear is `ExternalCookie`, maybe I have missed the whole thing. My understanding is when external login is successfully, external cookie is used to store the external claim identity. And then we call:

```
var result = await authManager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
authManager.SignOut("ExternalCookie");
```

In order to get the external claim identity and then convert external identity to local identity. I have a little bit confusion why we have to call `SignOut` external cookie in this case.

Also, I'm not sure whether External Cookie is a must when using external login, or do we have other ways around without using External Cookie.

Please someone give an explanation on this point.

Comment: To your first question re: SignOut, it's cleanup.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569396/why-call-signoutdefaultauthenticationtypes-externalcookie-before-use-of-applic).  To your third question re: "ExternalCookie" name, I am pretty sure this is simply to keep your auth code referring to the same cookie.  If you were to replace all instances of the string literal "ExternalCookie" in your code with, say, "BlergyBlergy", the functionality would still work.  Examine your browser cookies directly during the web lifecycle to illustrate.

Comment: Brock Allen has a great [primer on the whole external login subject here](http://brockallen.com/2014/01/09/a-primer-on-external-login-providers-social-logins-with-owinkatana-authentication-middleware/).

Comment: @ChrisSimmons: Thanks for the link, I also found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166826/usecookieauthentication-vs-useexternalsignincookie is very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your last question, you change the name of cookie in startup.auth file where you configure external cookie -

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

You can use a string instead of DefaultAuthenticationTypes enum and directly specify the name of the cookie like -

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie("myExternalCookie");
```

Comment: in your case you are already using strings, so you just need to specify a different name.